# How to test ratio of the relation?

Tags: php, unit-testing, activerecord, yii2

I declared `workAbroads` relationship for the class `WorkType` and `workType` relationship for the class `WorkAbroad`:

```
class WorkType extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    ...

    public function getWorkAbroads()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(WorkAbroad::className(), ['WorkTypeID' => 'ID']);
    }
}

class WorkAbroad extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    ...

    public function getWorkType()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(WorkType::className(), ['ID' => 'WorkTypeID']);
    }
}
```

I would like to test the ratio of the relation. How to do it properly?

Suppose that I created one `$workType` object and one hundred `$workAbroads` objects.

I expect that the following expression will return an array of the `$workAboards` objects:

```
$workAboards = $workType->getWorkAbroads(); // The SQL query is always executed
// $workAboards = $workType->workAbroads; // The SQL query will be executed once
```

Then the following check succeeds:

```
assertEquals(100, count($workAbroads));
```

Instead, I get the following error:

```
Failed asserting that 1 matches expected 100
```

I know that I can test the relation by querying all the ActiveRecord objects `WorkAbroad` for which the following is true:

```
'WorkTypeID' => $workType->ID
```

But I would like to understand why the first method doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$workType->getWorkAbroads()` will return an [`ActiveQuery`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html) object, not an array of `WorkAbroad` objects, you should simply try :

```
$workAboards = $workType->getWorkAbroads()->all();
```

But if you just want to count related records, you should use this :

```
assertEquals(100, $workType->getWorkAbroads()->count());
```